# Search and replace with sed when dots and underscores are present

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

How do I replace `foo.` with `foo_` with sed simply running

```bash
sed 's/foo./foo_/g' file.php
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show us some lines of `file.php` where the replace doesn't work as it should do ?

Answer (score 52):

Escape the `.`:

```
sed 's/foo\./foo_/g' file.php
```

Example:

```
~$ cat test.txt 
foo.bar
~$ sed 's/foo\./foo_/g' test.txt 
foo_bar
```

Comment: Thanks!..i don't need to escape the "_" in "foo_"?

Comment: Check out the [ed(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ed+1) manual page at the "Regular Expressions" section to find out what you can use in the left and right side of the expression. Also, take a look at [regex(7)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?regex+7) for an explanation of POSIX.2 regular expressions.

Answer (score 22):

Interestingly, if you want to search for and replace just the dot, you have to put the dot in a character set. Escaping just the dot alone in a sed command for some reason doesn't work. The dot is still expanded to a single character wild card.

```bash
bash --version  # Ubuntu Lucid (10.04)
```

GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Replaces all characters with dash:

```bash
echo aa.bb.cc | sed s/\./-/g
# --------
```

Replaces the dots with a dash:

```bash
echo aa.bb.cc | sed s/[.]/-/g
# aa-bb-cc
```

With the addition of leading characters in the search, the escape works.

```bash
echo foo. | sed s/foo\./foo_/g  # works
# foo_
```

Putting the dot in a character set of course also works.

```bash
echo foo. | sed s/foo[.]/foo_/g  # also works
# foo_
```

Comment: You are trying to escape the dot withing the shell, so sed treats it as "any character". Try `echo foo8 | sed s/foo\./foo_/g` and you still get `foo_`. To prevent escaping by shell, use quotes: `echo aa.bb.cc | sed 's/\./-/g'` will give `aa-bb-cc`;

Answer (score 9):

Escape the dot with a \

```
sed 's/foo\./foo_/g' file.php
```

If you find the combination of / and \ confusing you can use another 'separator' character

```
sed 's#foo\.#foo_#g
```

The 2nd character after the s can be anything and sed will use that character as a separator.

Comment: Not familiar to `sed`, but is last `/` really necessary in 2nd example, where `#` is used as a separator?

Comment: @binaryLV: Thanks - it's not needed.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the dot - an unescaped dot will match any character after foo.

```
sed 's/foo\./foo_/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

For myself, `sed 's/foo\./foo_/g'` is working.  But you can also try:

```
sed -e 's/foo\./foo_/g'
```

and

```
sed -e "s/foo\\./foo_/g"
```

and

```
sed 's/foo[.]/foo_/g'
```