# How do I simultaneously replace ":" and ";" with a newline?

Tags: alias, csh, setenv

## Background

The [tr](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html) command translates, delete, or squeezes characters from standard input. I am trying to create a [cshell alias](https://www.decf.berkeley.edu/help/unix/csh/aliases.html) that outputs the [`setenv`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetenv.htm) command such that each file or directory in the path is displayed on a new line.

In other words, I want this example output of `setenv`:

> PATH=/some/dir:/some/second/dir:/some/third/dir
>
> PROFILES= file:///some/file/here.txt;file:///some/second/file.xml;file:///some/third/file/there.pl

To become this:

> PATH= /some/dir
>
> /some/second/dir
>
> /some/third/dir
>
> PROFILES= file:///some/file/here.txt
>
> file:///some/second/file.xml
>
> file:///some/third/file/there.pl

## Related Aliases that work

I have created aliases that output the individual environment variables like above:

1. For PATH:
   `alias readablePath = 'echo "$PATH" | tr : '\'\\\n\'' '`
2. For PROFILES:
   `alias readableProfiles= 'echo "$PROFILES" | tr \; 'echo "$PATH" | tr : '\'\\\n\'' '`

## Attempted aliases that do not work

These are the aliases that I have tried that return `tr: no match`.

1. `alias readEnv 'echo "setenv" | tr [:\;]  '\'\\\n\'' '`
2. `alias readEnv 'echo setenv | tr [:\;]  '\'\\\n\'' '`
3. `alias readEnv 'echo setenv | tr [:\\;] '\'\\\n\'' '`
4. `alias readEnv 'echo setenv | tr [:;] '\'\\\n\'' '`

These are the aliases that I have tried that return the string `"setenv"`.

5. `alias readEnv 'echo setenv | tr "[:;]" '\'\\\n\'' '`
6. `alias readEnv 'echo "setenv" | tr "[:;]" '\'\\\n\'' '`

## Question

How do I create an alias that successfully takes the output of `setenv` and inserts a newline where there is a ":" or a ";"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace multiple characters in your (unix/linux) command line alias, you should rather use sed and regular expressions, as in [Search and replace with sed when dots and underscores are present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123915/search-and-replace-with-sed-when-dots-and-underscores-are-present) .
So something like:

```
sed 's/\.\|,/\\n/g'
```

where `\.` finds a dot (needs to be escaped, else it finds any character), `\|` is the or operation, also escaped, and the new line also must have its `\\` escaped.