# Sed replace string with another string wrong result

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

I need to replace `../` with `./` from below line.

```
<html xmlns:og="http://test.org/schema/"  xmlns:website="../test/ns/website" >
```

But when use the command

`sed -i 's+../+./+g' ./*`

The file content changed to

`<html xmlns:og="htt.//test.o./sche./"  xmlns:website="./te././website" >`

What could be the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace with sed when dots and underscores are present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6123915/608639), [Use sed with variable that contains dot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39659946/608639), [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907) and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
echo "<html xmlns:og="http://test.org/schema/"  xmlns:website="../test/ns/website" >" | sed 's|\.\./|./|g'
<html xmlns:og=http://test.org/schema/  xmlns:website=./test/ns/website >
```

You need to escape the `.` or else it mean any character.

This should work as well:
`sed 's+\.\./+./+g`'